# Why does calling -allValues on an NSDictionary throw an exception?

Tags: objective-c, exception, nsdictionary

I try to get all values from nsdictionary, but it throw an exception at second line

```
NSDictionary* thetimeLineDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSArray* theallTweets = [thetimeLineDict allValues];
```

below is the exception from console

```
2011-11-27 14:56:38.156 SparkTweet[2066:1390b] -[__NSCFArray allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8128310
2011-11-27 14:56:38.158 SparkTweet[2066:1390b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8128310'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14c0052 0x189cd0a 0x14c1ced 0x1426f00 0x1426ce2 0x2c48 0x33306 0x1b38445 0x1b39ecf 0x1b39d28 0x1b394af 0x9b632b24 0x9b6346fe)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Looks like `JSONObjectWIthData:options:error:` is returning an array. Are you sure it should return a dictionary?

Comment: (Remember, the type of a pointer variable in Objective C does not at all control the type of the object actually pointed to.  It just permits the compiler to diagnose obvious errors, nothing more.)

Answer (score 7):

Because `allValues` is not a valid method for NSArray, which is what was returned.

A JSON parser doesn't always return a dictionary as the outermost Objective-C object.  Rather, what you get back depends on what JSON text was fed in, and the JSON text fed in had an array (`[]`) as the outermost structure.

(Note that as a general rule you should always test the result from a JSON parser to see what type was returned, unless you know for absolute certainty that it will always be array or, alternatively, "object"/dictionary.)

Comment: Thanks, dude, you are right. This JSON text has array with '[]'. I tried return NSArray, it works. Can you tell me how to check the type of a object.

Comment: To check the type of object use the NSObject protocol method `isKindOfClass:`

Comment: Yep, `isKindOfClass:` is generally the best way to check the object type.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:) for how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The JSON you are reading contains an Array not an NSDictionary, you can test this by calling the following after doing the data parsing:

```
NSLog(@"The class is %@",[thetimeLineDict class]);
```

The output will probably be:

```
2011-11-27 14:56:38.156 SparkTweet[2066:1390b]:The class is NSArray
```

The problem might be that you have an array of dictionaries not just a dictionary.